# GDB C++ - Inspecting STL Containers when looking at a core dump?

Tags: c++, stl, gdb, coredump

I'm debugging a core dump of my program (post-mortem) inside gdb. I opened it with:
    gdb [program_name] [core_name]

However when I attempt to inspect a STL vector, e.g.
    print vec->size()
or
    print vec->at(0)

I get the error

> "You can't do that without a process to debug"

I'm just trying to inspect the contents and sizes of these containers. Is there any way to attach a dummy process to a core-dump gdb inspection so I can do this?

Comment: What version of gdb are you using? Depending on the version you can search for STL pretty printers that will process the memory and generate a human readable presentation of the containers. http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

Comment: You're attempting to call functions which you can't do when post-mortem debugging.  Just examine the vectors memory instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

print the vector:

```
(gdb) print *vec
```

Then familiarize yourself with the internals of your implementation's vector and print the raw buffer.  Often called "_M_buffer" or something like that.  Depending on how yours is done there may be an internal object that the buffer is inside of.