# how to debug a C++ programer whic not goin to man and crash?

Tags: c++, linux, curl

I wrote a cpp file that can be compiled and run, but when I run it I get gdb tips: `bad::alloc`. I set a break-point at the first line of `main` function, and it did not reach it, which means the program is not going into `main` function.

```
16:51:33: Debugging starts
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

```
0x7fffedc67169  <+  169>        48 3d 00 f0 ff ff           cmp    $0xfffffffffffff000,%rax
0x7fffedc6716f  <+  175>        77 3f                       ja     0x7fffedc671b0 <__GI_raise+240>
0x7fffedc67171  <+  177>        41 89 c0                    mov    %eax,%r8d
        ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/internal-signals.h:
0x7fffedc67174  <+  180>        41 ba 08 00 00 00           mov    $0x8,%r10d
0x7fffedc6717a  <+  186>        31 d2                       xor    %edx,%edx
0x7fffedc6717c  <+  188>        4c 89 ce                    mov    %r9,%rsi
0x7fffedc6717f  <+  191>        bf 02 00 00 00              mov    $0x2,%edi
0x7fffedc67184  <+  196>        b8 0e 00 00 00              mov    $0xe,%eax
0x7fffedc67189  <+  201>        0f 05                       syscall
        ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:
0x7fffedc6718b  <+  203>        48 8b 84 24 08 01 00 00     mov    0x108(%rsp),%rax
0x7fffedc67193  <+  211>        64 48 33 04 25 28 00 00 00  xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
0x7fffedc6719c  <+  220>        75 26                       jne    0x7fffedc671c4 <__GI_raise+260>
0x7fffedc6719e  <+  222>        44 89 c0                    mov    %r8d,%eax
0x7fffedc671a1  <+  225>        48 81 c4 18 01 00 00        add    $0x118,%rsp
0x7fffedc671a8  <+  232>        c3                          retq
0x7fffedc671a9  <+  233>        0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00        nopl   0x0(%rax)
        46 [1]  in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c
0x7fffedc671b0  <+  240>        48 8b 15 b9 4c 1a 00        mov    0x1a4cb9(%rip),%rdx        # 0x7fffede0be70
0x7fffedc671b7  <+  247>        f7 d8                       neg    %eax
0x7fffedc671b9  <+  249>        41 b8 ff ff ff ff           mov    $0xffffffff,%r8d
0x7fffedc671bf  <+  255>        64 89 02                    mov    %eax,%fs:(%rdx)
0x7fffedc671c2  <+  258>        eb b0                       jmp    0x7fffedc67174 <__GI_raise+180>
0x7fffedc671c4  <+  260>        e8 a7 c7 0e 00              callq  0x7fffedd53970 <__stack_chk_fail>
```

Comment: steps to reproduce?

Comment: This attempt at the question is no better than the last: [What is the reason of what(): bad::alloc in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63380634/what-is-the-reason-of-what-badalloc-in-linux).

Comment: not reaching main() means that it happens during construction or initialization of global scope's objects.

Comment: Also useful in addition to aforementioned answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399973/gdb-c-inspecting-stl-containers-when-looking-at-a-core-dump

Comment: @user4581301 yeah, i think so, but is display closed. helpless.